# Anyone knows what might be the problem with this video output?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am seeing the following scrambled output for a live stream when processing an udp input stream. I am using the recently downloaded ffmpeg from GIT. Stop and Start of ffmpeg command resolves the issues temporarily.

[image: Scrambled out]
Sample Logs:

```
    Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020 ffmpeg version N-94528-gfaa9cd3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-lm --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libavcodec     58. 55.100 / 58. 55.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libavformat    58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libavfilter     7. 58.100 /  7. 58.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Sun Jan 26 03:52:00 2020   libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100


Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4d988c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4e54f80] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020     Last message repeated 1 times
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4e54f80] Missing reference picture, default is 56257016
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020     Last message repeated 1 times
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc2e00] mmco: unref short failure
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x594f4c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4f66800] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4f66800] Missing reference picture, default is 56257692
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4c75a00] mmco: unref short failure
Sun Jan 26 04:02:46 2020 [h264 @ 0x4d988c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4e54f80] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020     Last message repeated 1 times
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4e54f80] Missing reference picture, default is 56257032
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020     Last message repeated 1 times
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc16c0] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc16c0] Missing reference picture, default is 56257700
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc2e00] mmco: unref short failure
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x594f4c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 udp://230.1.1.2:12000?fifo_size=5000000&overrun_nonfatal=1: corrupt decoded frame in stream 3
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4f66800] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4f66800] Missing reference picture, default is 56257708
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4c75a00] mmco: unref short failure
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4d988c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4e54f80] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020     Last message repeated 1 times
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4e54f80] Missing reference picture, default is 56257048
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020     Last message repeated 1 times
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc16c0] reference picture missing during reorder
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc16c0] Missing reference picture, default is 56257716
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x4cc2e00] mmco: unref short failure
Sun Jan 26 04:02:47 2020 [h264 @ 0x594f4c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
```

Comment: Video format is ts?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, UDP packets get loss or reordered, and this results in "Missing reference picture" error and "scrambled" video output.
Or ffmpeg is not able to decode the stream in realtime and thus is skipping some packets.

Comment: Okay.  I was under the impression, that iframes are missing from the source. Is there any way to fix this? Can we force ffmpeg to insert keyframe by using --keyint param.

Comment: Do you control the input stream? Are you using ffmpeg for encode/stream? Whats the command line?
Yes, periodic keyframes every second should significantly improve the resiliency of the stream. 
What is the command line for ffmpeg on receiving side?

Comment: We get the source as UDP. Yes, we use ffmpeg to push it to our rtmp server.  Please see the below command line.

Comment: ffmpeg -err_detect aggressive -fflags discardcorrupt -i udp://x.x.x.x fifo_size=5000000&buffer_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1 -analyzeduration 25M -probesize 50M -threads 0 -vsync 1 -filter_complex [i:0x550]yadif,setdar=11/9[1out1] -map [1out1] -map i:0x528-c:v libx264 -x264-params keyint=50:scenecut=0:nal-hrd=cbr -b:v 100k -maxrate 100k -bufsize 150k -r 25 -g 50 -profile:v high -level 4.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -sc_threshold 0 -s 176x144 -tune film -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -x264opts opencl -f flv rtmp://x.x.x.x:1935/rtmp/test

Comment: You should enable 1 second keyframe interval in source udp stream to improve its resiliency.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment.
I guess you are receiving ts over udp (sat?).
Why you set threads 0? ffmpeg streaming guide recommends to use multiple threads, so that the receiving thread can work w/o interruptions.
First, I would check that pure udp receiving works ok - just save input ts in a file, and check it for errors.
If it has the same errors, it means ffmpeg cannot receive all udp packets in time - look at the network configuration on your server, for example receive buffer size.
If pure receiving works ok, it means your output is a bottleneck, which slows the receiving.